# Can't link to SharePoint 2013 document or site from within Word

Tags: 2013, office

We have two users (so far) that when they click on a link in a Word document to another document in a SharePoint 2013 library, they get a **405 error - Method Not Allowed**. The browser address is the virtual _trust site.

If they copy and paste the link into the browser, they can access the document with no problems.

If they try to click on a link to a SharePoint 2013 site from within a document, they get **"This site has not been shared with you"**. Again, they can navigate to the site or paste the link and go there directly.

We cannot replicate the issue, it only happens to these two users, but it may affect more that we don't know about.

The logs don't show an error as such, but when they try to access it, we get:

- *Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=False, UserIdentityName=, ClaimsCount=0*
- *Failure when fetching document. 0x80070005*
- *System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))*

I have tried just placing a link in a fresh new document, nothing else, and they still get the error.

I've tried changing open in client/open in browser/default, but it has no effect.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before?

Comment: Are you using Office 2013, if so are the users signed in with a different account than the one they would access SharePoint with? 
Also (clutching at straws here) try running a repair of the Office install.

Comment: Is the link in the Word document formatted as a UNC path (\\server\... and therefore using WebDAV) or as a URL (http://...)? Do you get the same behaviour for both types of links?

Comment: Office 2013 seems to work fine, and one user with Office 2010 worked fine too. However, we've noticed that the Office 2010 user that can't access it is a few minor versions behind the 2010 user that can access it. We're trying to update it now...